# Need some hints for choosing win32 file APIs

Tags: windows, c++11

As I am writing a lexer, I want to avoid as much as possible allocations, so I start by getting the file size to allocate a bunch of tokens based on a heuristic. By doing that I asking my self if the Windows kernel can get the file size with GetFileSizeEx without reading it completely, which will add a latency before I will be able to start lexing?

Does the filesystem starting to fill memory cache immediately when a file handle is open? Because GetFileSizeEx need an open file.

And after I am considering to read my file asynchronously with ReadFileScatter or ReadFileEx. But I can't figure out what is the real difference between those functions, as ReadFileEx can be used with double-buffering to be able to lex a chunk while the next one is filled in background.

ReadFileScatter seems to be a bit more complicated to use as chunks have to be pre-allocated since the beginning with memory aligned to system pages. Does someone know why it is so?

What about FileMapping functions, can it be interesting for my purpose?

PS: Files will stay open during the entire application life.

Comment: Why not just use an incremental read approach, and then have an incomplete API for the lexer than incrementally generates tokens. That way you can read a fixed-sized buffer (maybe, 4096-8192 bytes), incrementally generate tokens, and then when an incomplete token is found, continue reading and generating more tokens. It won't require any allocations, and should scale fairly well. Please note this won't actually consider the parser, which may need to have a much larger context in order to efficiently parse said tokens.

Comment: Also, generally, to my knowledge, most compilers (I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to write) can't avoid allocations, but for performance, some actually no-op free and then just return everything back to the system when the process exits (since it's a short-lived program). Notable compilers that do this include the D reference compiler (DMD).

Comment: Using FileMapping lets the OS use the already efficient paging system to read blocks of the file into memory. It is definitely worth exploring for your use case.

Comment: I just realized that it will add complexity if my tokens can be on multiple memory chunks, so I really need to have only one buffer that represent the entire file content. the thing is it can be filled as the same time as I'll do lexing. I'll look if it is possible to use mapped file asynchronously. @AlexanderHuszagh I followed D, but for now I am doing some experimentation based on JAI language.

Comment: *Does the filesystem starting to fill memory cache immediately when a file handle is open* - no, only after first read or write. also you can use `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` for disable cache on file